# Can someone tell a formal definition for this problem: k-disjoint triangle?

Tags: data-structures, parameterized-complexity

k-disjoint triangle
"We consider the NP-complete problem of deciding whether an input graph on n vertices has k vertex-disjoint copies of a fixed graph H. "

The above definition is the best I could find online. Nowhere could I find an clear formal definition.

1. What does it mean to be vertex disjoint exactly?
2. How to prove k-disjoint vertex is NP hard?

Comment: Can you provide attribution for the source you are quoting?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the case in which $H$ is a triangle; the general case is very similar.

A *triangle* in a graph $G$ is a set $\{x,y,z\}$ of three vertices of $G$ such that $G$ contains the edges $\{x,y\},\{y,z\},\{z,x\}$. Two triangles $T_1,T_2$ are *(vertext) disjoint* if they do not share a vertex: $T_1 \cap T_2 = \varnothing$. A graph contains $k$ disjoint triangles if it contains $k$ triangles $T_1,\ldots,T_k$ which are pairwise disjoint: $T_i \cap T_j = \varnothing$ for all $i \neq j$.

Your quote is taken from the paper [Exact algorithms for finding $k$ disjoint triangles in an arbitrary graph](http://mrfellows.net/papers/C62-wg2004.pdf) by Fellows, Heggernes, Rosamond, Sloper, and Telle. Here is the last sentence of the first paragraph:

> On the other hand, the $K_3$-packing problem, which is our main concern in this paper, is NP-hard [HK78].

The $K_3$-packing problem asks, given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, whether $G$ contains $k$ disjoint triangles. The reference [HK78], which can be found in the bibliography of the paper, presumably contains a proof that this problem is NP-complete.

Answer (score 2):

Finding $k$ disjoint triangles in a graph means that you color $3k$ vertices with $k$ colors, $\chi_i, 1 \leq i \leq k$ such that for each color $\chi_i$, the graph $G[X_i] \simeq K_3$, where $X_i$ are the three vertices that received color $\chi_i$.

It simply means that you cannot use the same vertex in two different triangles.

This type of problem is often referred to as $K_3$-packing or triangle-packing: You want to "pack" as many triangles as possible in a graph $G$.

The problem is NP-complete even if you are given a tri-partition of the graph, and this problem is called [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching), one of [Karp's 21 NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).